# Good clean bulking meals

Tags: diet, weight-gain, muscle-mass, food, muscle-gain

I've been clean bulking for a long while but after eating the same things for a long while it gets hard to keep eating it every day. Do you guys have any advice on meals with many complex carbs, protein, and calories?

My list is primarily as follows:

```
- Brown rice
- Whole wheat pasta
- Eggs
- Oats
- Peanutbutter
- Potatoes
- Can of tuna (preferably in olive oil)
- Chicken fillet (mostly in rice or nasi)

My caloriebomb shake recipe (credits to buffdudes)
- Massgainer
- 150gr fine oats
- Banana
- 2 spoons of peanutbutter
- water (or milk but I think water tastes just fine)

Blend it and you will have a 1000-1500 calorie shake with 
complex carbs + good fats + proteins + all that you would want from a massgainer
```

Do you guys have anything else to add to the list for the sake of variation? Eating the same things all day really gets boring after a while and tempting to cheat.

Comment: Where's the meat?

Comment: What defines "clean" versus "dirty" for you? There's nothing wrong with doing so, it's just not clear what the distinction is from person to person.

Comment: Meals that are rich in complex carbs, protein, good fats. Containing low to no sugar, and ofcourse no fast-food. Just healthy easy to prepare food that could be used in bulking. I'm just looking for new information about foods because I lack variety. Good point on the meat I will edit my question a little although I don't have many variations of meat either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly consider dramatically increasing your intake of grass-fed meat. The fat can be good for you. A large grass-fed steak with a side of veggies drenched in butter from grass-fed cows is tremendously delicious, allows for great variety by changing up the choice of veggies, and is powerfully anabolic when eaten in sufficient quantities. Pastured pork can be swapped in for the grass-fed steak.

For fat, coconut oil and large quantities of high-quality olive oil (over greens, for instance) should not be overlooked.

For carbs, sweet potatoes are an excellent alternative to potatoes. Higher-carb vegetables like carrots and beets are also delicious.

Comment: Beef/turkey/chicken + sweet potatoes = mmm mmm good.

Comment: Why is sweet potato an excellent alternative? Reading the "Nutrient content of 10 major staple foods" from the sweet potato wiki article, I don't see it being a clear winner over regular potato. More of this, less of that and quit a lot more sugar.

Comment: @RusI They make a good alternative because they're similar, but delicious in a different way. I'm not saying they're superior, I'm saying they're both great and taste different from each other, thus satisfying the "variety" goal.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Just tried sweet potatoes for the first time, baked ones. It is a weird feeling, as if eating regular potatoes mixed with sugar. I think it should make an excellent mashed potato recipe.

Comment: @RusI that's great!